# Line detection from a picture

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

[image: picture to be detected - different color]
picture to be detected - different color

For a picture like above, the lines are blue, I use mask to get the contours of these lines, please see below code:

```
img = cv2.imread("./more5.png")#"https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiLPv.png"
blueLower = np.array([50,50,50])
blueUpper = np.array([130,255,255])
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
blue_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, blueLower, blueUpper)
blue = cv2.bitwise_and(img ,img ,mask=blue_mask)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(preprocess(blue), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

[image: Lines detected]
Lines detected

complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def preprocess(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5, 5), 1)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 50, 50) # edge cascade
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=1) 
    img_erode = cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=1)
    return img_erode

# BGR to HSV to LAB to ...

def find_tip(points, convex_hull):
    length = len(points)
    indices = np.setdiff1d(range(length), convex_hull)

    for i in range(2):
        j = indices[i] + 2
        if j > length - 1:
            j = length - j
        if np.all(points[j] == points[indices[i - 1] - 2]):
            return tuple(points[j])

img = cv2.imread("./more5.png")

blueLower = np.array([50,50,50])
blueUpper = np.array([130,255,255])

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
blue_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, blueLower, blueUpper)
blue = cv2.bitwise_and(img ,img ,mask=blue_mask)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(preprocess(blue), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 

print(f"Contours size {len(contours)}") #

for cnt in contours:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True) #
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.004 * peri, True) #
    hull = cv2.convexHull(approx, returnPoints=False)
    sides = len(hull) #

    if 6 > sides > 3 and sides + 2 == len(approx):
        arrow_tip = find_tip(approx[:,0,:], hull.squeeze())
        if arrow_tip:
            cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
            cv2.circle(img, arrow_tip, 3, (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However, if the line and the connected shape is the SAME color (please see the picture below), this method does NOT work anymore, how can I detect the lines from such a picture? Thanks for any ideas!

[image: picture to be detected - same color]
picture to be detected - same color

Answer (score 1):

If your graph is a tree (it does not has closed circuits), then only the lines are connected to the same area on both sides.

If you paint the external area of the same color, only the lines will have the same color on both sides

[image]

Then you can do a convolution to have the lines averaged with the external space color, and the other lines averaged with the internal spaces color

[image: different colors]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#download the example image from this webpage
from PIL import Image as Pim
from io import BytesIO
import requests
photoURL="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiLPv.png"

response = requests.get(photoURL)

image = np.array(Pim.open(BytesIO(response.content)).convert('L'))  # Convert to greyscale
#mask to only 2 colors
gray=128
black=0
Monochrome = lambda t: gray if t!=image[0,0] else black #If color<>upper left color, then it is 0, else is 1
vfunc = np.vectorize(Monochrome)
image=vfunc(image)


#fill the external space with the same color as the upper left pixel
import cv2

UpperLeftPixel=(0,0)
AdjacentColor=255#White
imajeAdjacent=cv2.floodFill(image, None, UpperLeftPixel, AdjacentColor)


#convolution to average colors of lines with neighbor spaces
averagingFilter=np.ones(shape=(9,9))/9**2

import scipy
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2d
image=conv2d(image,averagingFilter, mode="same")

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```